# Achieve an output of 0-5v using 2 hall sensors as the inputs

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

I am modifying a kids ride-on car to use brushless motors with VESCs, but I wish to use 1 hall sensor pedal for accelerator and a 2nd identical pedal for regenerative braking.
I have seen that a server tester can be used between a hall sensor accelerator and an ESC or VESC where the server tester can convert the hall sensor 1-4v signal to PWM for the ESC quite easily, as can be seen here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?fbclid=IwAR3_tVIt20qbNBgBcchpa_ioEIgs-w6Vu9u-UVrzC7BLmhRJMzwLWKs_U_Q&v=cceUTv6tAaA

I want to have an accelerator pedal, when released leaves the motor just coasting and no regenerative braking enabled yet, but when the brake pedal is pressed regenerative braking starts to come into effect. I would also like the accelerator pedal signal to be ignored when the brake pedal starts to be depressed, so the brake pedal overrides the accelerator pedal when both are depressed.
I was thinking this could possibly be done with some op amps, but as it has been around 40 years since I did any electronic theory I have no idea to design such a circuit now.

I will start doing some research meanwhile, but some suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Any help in the way of example circuitry would be greatly appreciated

Comment: it would be really easy with a micro, is that allowed or do you need discretes?

Comment: There are no limitations on what I can use, but I have no coding skills, just some understanding of some basic concepts.

Comment: You'll be impressed at how much can be achieved with an Arduino and pleasantly surprised at the relatively gentle learning process. There are many choice modules available and examples come with the basic install. / An op amp solution is also not overly complex.

Comment: You seem decently capable, and it's never been easier. You can even use drag and drop "blocks" based programming (ex tinkercad's circuits) these days, but that sort of a "program" is only a dozen simple lines of code or so, i bet you could make a weekend project out of it. Having it digital makes it really easy to tune  and customize, like if for some reason one pedal inflects only 1.7v - 3.9v and one spans 1.1v to 4.2v, you can easily make them behave "full range" by adjusting one variable... It's also going to be a lot less wiring and solder to use a micro, that why I fell in love.

Comment: I am starting to lean towards the Arduino path, I have been curious about them for quite a while, but was always a bit hesitant as I thought it would be a steep learning curve. But that doesn't sound like it is the case. I do like the fact they would be easier to tune than a circuit.
Can you please suggest a place to learn the basics and get me off the ground with them? I might even go and buy something today and get started, the weekend is only just beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, I have already achieved what I wanted to do just with LED brightness with 2 pedals and PWD for LED output. Just gotta wait for the VESCs to arrive and work out how to interface with it.